# Problems to get related fields serialized (manytomany etc) ... looking for good practices

Tags: django, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I've got some problems to understand the right way serializing data with django-rest-framework e.g. using data from related models.

Let me explain a little bit my situation:
I have an Organization model with a manytomany relation to a Subtopic model classifying each organiaztion. Further each subtopic belongs to a general topic.
In addition there is an OrgaDataSet model to save crawled data for each organization in a PostgreSQL JSONField. The field "type" in the OrgaDataSet Model should give me a kind of flexibility to classify crawled data in further stages.

```
# models.py

class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class Subtopic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    subtopics = models.ManyToManyField(Subtopic)

class OrgaDataSet(models.Model):
    data_set_types = (
        ('ADDRESS', 'address'),
        ('PERSON', 'person'),
        ('DIVISION', 'division'),
    )
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=data_set_types)
    crawled_data = JSONField(verbose_name='Data set')
```

But lets come up with my questions / problems:
1. How can I serialize the related data with minimized database requests and get an customized serialized field like:

```
"topics_list": [
        {
            "topic_name": "Medical science",
            "subtopics": [
                "Dental products",
                "Hygiene"
            ]
        },
        {
            "topic_name": "Biotechnology",
            "subtopics": [
                "Microbiology"
            ]
        }
    ],
```

I tried different approaches: amongst others a custom model manager to add a method "get_topics_list", however I'm sticking with the right way to query with "prefetch_related" and "select_related" ... But is this even the richt way?
Also I tried to set up a serializedMethodField in the serializer itself. However I was asking myself what is the best place to do the related query, in the view.py or in the serializers.py?

2. My second question concerns the OrgaDataSet model. I am absolutly uncertain how and where to place the queries, one for each "type". Should I do a specific method in the custom model manager for each type, like "get_type_address"?

I would appreciate your ideas and any hint to understand the utilization of the django-framework a little bit more.

Thanks a lot,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Question 1)
   This is typical Category/Subcategory problem. I would suggest to look at the following django package : https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt

It would store Topics/Subtopics in one table ( tree structure ), making the queries efficient and you can easily produce the desired output efficiently

Question 2)
This depends how you want to display the data. Do you have one endpoint for each type ?

If you have one endpoint for each type, you can do a view like this :

```
class OrgaDataSetListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    type = None
    serializer_class =<your serializer>

    def get_queryset(self):
       return OrgaDataSet.objects.filter(type=self.type)
```

And use it like this in urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('orgadata/address', OrgaDataSetListView.as_view(type='ADDRESS')),
    path('orgadata/person', OrgaDataSetListView.as_view(type='PERSON')),
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Regarding 1) I will go for your suggestion, that sounds like the solution I was looking for.
The challenge in 2) is more like that I want to get all data in one single ListAPIView  (one endpoint) and not for each type separately.

Comment: then is easy. just make one query to get all the data ( one call), organize in the way you like and return result